# Change height of span with text overflowing to next line

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I'm making a web page inspired by the U.S. Constitution, and I'm having a weird CSS problem. Here's what the relevant part looks like:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<span id="we-the-people" class="ui image">
  <img src="/images/we-the-people.png">
</span>

<span id="preamble">
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</span>
```

... and CSS:

```
#we-the-people {
  margin: 2em;
}
#preamble {
  font-family: US Declaration, serif;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px; 
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

I'd like the text that overflows to the second line to be closer to the "We the People" image, but I can't figure out how to do so. I've tried changing `line-height` and `position` to no avail. What seems so strange is that the overflowing text is well below the bottom of the image, as this screenshot of inspecting the page shows:

[image]

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try removing the bottom `2em` margin from `#we-the-people` style like this:

   ```
    margin: 2em 2em 0 2em;
   /*Assuming you need the 2em margin top, right and left*/
   ```
2. Remove the `position: relative;` and `top: 35px;` entries in the `#preamble` style.
3. Line height will also affect the vertical spacing, especially if you use `ems` or `%` as these cascade from the parent font size and can lead to strange spacing.

I would recommend you use multipliers with line-height, like this:

```
 line-height: 1.2;
```

Note that no units value is included. `1.2` would give a line height `1.2x` the height of the font. Lower values (including negative values) can be used to move each line closer to the previous one (including overlapping lines should you need to), larger values increase leading and move the lines further apart.

Also the font name `'US Constitution'` should be in quotes as it contains a space. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I made those changes, but it moved the whole section of text up. That is, the overflowing part moved closer to "We the People", but the first line text also moved up (by the same amount). Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the `#we-the-people` style. You may need to try different values to get the effect you're after.